# New Windows XP updates started to show up in fall 2014

Tags: windows-xp, security, windows-update

Since Windows XP support ended in April 2014, my automatic update client went quiet. But about two months ago updates started to show up in it again!

Naturally, I was suspicious that Microsoft might be trying to break existing installations and examined what was listed there (my settings are "ask to download and ask to install"):

- Most of them are old security updates for "Windows XP" and .NET Framework, mostly from 2013 (examples: [KB2893984](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2893984), [KB2833940](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2833940)). These do fit the "break existing installations" pattern since installing them over newer ones will re-introduce security holes that were patched later on;
- Some are updates for MS Office 2007 (e.g. [KB2883032](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2883032)). These seem legit since it is still supported;
- Some are OS-independent, like the malicious software removal tool. Same as the previous one.

The questions are:

- **Did any security specialists analyze these strange new updates?** (assuming I’m not the only one who experiences this phenomenon)
- **Can anyone shed more light on what is going on?**

Comment: I am prety sure that Miscrosoft is not making any updated to retired products, is it possible that someone/something tampered with your certificates, and you computer is getting updates from fake microsoft server?

Comment: @sgp667: That's highly unlikely since relevant certificates are bundled with the autoupdate client, i believe, and "they" should've also tampered with DNS servers or routing across a few locations (the machine is a notebook that I carry around a bunch).

Comment: Do you have something that might have uninstalled the updates?

Comment: @Nemo this does seem to be the reason, see http://superuser.com/questions/829149/new-updates-started-to-show-up-in-fall-2014/1167835#1167835 below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Examining system metadata on the installed updates with `wmic qfe list brief`](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/quick-and-easy-way-list-all-windows-updates-installed-your-system.htm) shows no updates for WinXP and .NET Framework. This must be the reason.

```
Description                                                                                                     FixComments  HotFixID             InstallDate  InstalledBy  InstalledOn  Name  ServicePackInEffect  Status  
                                                                                                                             File 1                                                            KB2936068-IE7                
                                                                                                                             File 1                                                            KB2964358-IE7                
                                                                                                                             File 1                                                            KB835221WXP                  
                                                                                                                             Q147222                                                                                        
Исправление для MSXML 2 (KB887606)                                                                Update       KB887606_26                       SYSTEM       7/15/2008          SP6                          
Security update for MSXML4 SP2 (KB954430)                                                                                    Q954430                                        16.02.2009                                      
Security update for MSXML4 SP2 (KB973688)                                                                                    Q973688                                        30.10.2010                                      
Security update for MSXML4 SP3 (KB2758694)                                                                                   Q2758694                                       06.10.2016                                      
Microsoft Internationalized Domain Names Mitigation APIs                                                                     IDNMitigationAPIs                                                 SP1                          
Microsoft National Language Support Downlevel APIs                                                                           NLSDownlevelMapping                                               SP1                          
Hotfix for Windows Media Format 11 SDK (KB929399)                                                                            KB929399                                                                                       
Обновление безопасности для проигрывателя Windows Media - (KB2378111)                  KB2378111_WM9                                                                                  
Обновление безопасности для проигрывателя Windows Media - (KB2834904-v2)               KB2834904-v2_WM11                                                                              
Обновление безопасности для проигрывателя Windows Media - (KB952069)                   KB952069_WM9                                                                                   
Обновление безопасности для проигрывателя Windows Media - (KB954155)                   KB954155_WM9                                                                                   
Обновление безопасности для проигрывателя Windows Media - (KB973540)                   KB973540_WM9                                                                                   
Обновление безопасности для проигрывателя Windows Media - (KB975558)                   KB975558_WM8                                                                                   
Обновление безопасности для проигрывателя Windows Media - (KB978695)                   KB978695_WM9                                                                                   
Hotfix for Windows Media Player 11 (KB935957)                                                                                KB935957                                                                                       
Исправление для проигрывателя Windows Media 11 - (KB939683)                                       KB939683                                                                                       
Обновление безопасности для проигрывателя Windows Media 11 - (KB954154)                KB954154_WM11                                                                                  
Обновление безопасности для проигрывателя Windows Media 6.4 - (KB925398)               KB925398_WMP64                                                                                 
Обновление безопасности для проигрывателя Windows Media 9 - (KB936782)                 KB936782_WMP9                                                                                  
Обновление безопасности для Windows Internet Explorer 7 (KB2964358)                    Update       KB2964358-IE7                     SYSTEM       5/3/2014           SP0                          
High Definition Audio Driver Package - KB835221                                                                 Update       KB835221WXP                       Admin        10/16/2016         SP10                         
XML Paper Specification Shared Components Pack 1.0                                                                           XpsEPSC
```

After having the updates downloaded, I checked a few ones and did see that the files on my system have earlier versions than the ones in updates. So I indeed don't have them installed, it's not just broken metadata.

Most probably, I did a system restoration from the installation media at some point -- that's how they went missing. Judging by the older file versions and the fact that updates for libraries like MSXML that are not installed by the system setup are intact, this does seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Microsoft doesn't release new updates for Windows XP, they still supply existing updates. - They are available if somebody wants to make a new installation of Windows XP (about 250 updates!).
If you have installed other Microsoft programs lately, like MS Office, which is still supported, you might receive updates, that could be related to Windows XP.

As you have noticed, the "Malware-remover" (Windows Defender), still goes out monthly.

If you've changed from *Windows Update* to *Microsoft Update* (there's a link on Windows Update homepage), you might get a lot of "new" updates. - If not, you better do. Nobody knows how long they will be available. ;o)
Microsoft Update works a little slower, but it will update ALL Microsoft software.

Comment: This doesn't explain why there are _old_ security updates listed - my system already has them (or superseding ones) installed. _This_ is my primary concern.